# composition of 3D rigid transformations

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, motion-detection

This question belongs to the topic - 'Structure from Motion'.

Suppose, there are 3 images. There are point correspondences between image 1-2 and image 2-3, but there's no common point between image 1 and 3. I got the RT (rotation and translation matrix) of image 2, RT12, with respect to image 1(considering image 1 RT as [I|0], that means, rotation is identity, translation is zero). Lets split  RT12 into R12 and T12.

Similarly, I got RT23 considering image 2 RT as [I|0]. So, now I have R23 and T23, who are related to image 2, but not image 1. Now I want to find R13 and T13.

For a synthetic dataset, the equation R13=R23*R12 is giving correct R(verified, as I actually have the R13 precalculated). Similary T13 should be T2+T1. But the translation computed this way is bad. Since I have actual results with me, I could verify that Rotation was estimated nicely, but not translation. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe "A Mathematical Introduction to
Robotic Manipulation
", available at http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/books/MLS/pdf/mls94-complete.pdf might help

Comment: Also, you should change the title of your question, it is not about correspondences in 3 images but about composition of 3D rigid transformations.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple matrix block-multiplication problem, but you have to remember that you are actually considering 4x4 matrices (associated to rigid transformations in the 3D homogeneous world) and not 3x4 matrices.

**Your 3x4 RT matrices actually correspond to the first three rows of 4x4 matrices A, whose last rows are [0, 0, 0, 1]**:

RT23 -> A23=[R23, T23; 0, 0, 0, 1]

RT12 -> A12=[R12, T12; 0, 0, 0, 1]

Then, if you do the matrix block-multiplication on the 4x4 matrices (A13 = A23 * A12), you'll quickly find out that:

**R13 = R23 * R12**

**T13 = R23 * T12 + T23**

Comment: I'll try this and once I can confirm it works, will accept the answer. Thanks !